# Databricks jdbc driver. java.lang.ClassCastExeption: cannot be cast to java.lang.string

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, jdbc, driver

Trying to read a table from MS SQL Server using Spark. Took the Databricks example (https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/sql-databases.html)

Running the following scala code:

```
val jdbcHostname = "hostname"
val jdbcPort = 1433
val jdbcDatabase = "database"
val jdbcUrl = s"jdbc:sqlserver://${jdbcHostname}:${jdbcPort};database=${jdbcDatabase}"
import java.util.Properties
val connectionProperties = new Properties()
connectionProperties.put("user", s"${jdbcUsername}")
connectionProperties.put("password", s"${jdbcPassword}")
```

Getting the following exception:

```
scala> val stg = spark.read.jdbc(jdbcUrl, myTable, connectionProperties)
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.ColumnName cannot be cast to java.lang.String
  at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JPropertiesWrapper$$anon$3.next(Wrappers.scala:414)
  at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JPropertiesWrapper$$anon$3.next(Wrappers.scala:409)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
  at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
  at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
  at scala.collection.mutable.AbstractMap.$plus$plus$eq(Map.scala:80)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.jdbc(DataFrameReader.scala:235)
  ... 52 elided
```

What should I do in order to overcome this java exception?

Comment: Looks like you didn't share all the code. Also it would be nice to know exactly on which line the exceptions is thrown as well as full stacktrace.

Comment: The code was taken from https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/sql-databases.html - connect to SQL server and try to select a table

Comment: please put whole stack trace.

Comment: Above added the stack trace

Comment: Just to be sure - are `jdbcUsername` and `jdbcPassword` variables defined?

Comment: Yes, both are already defined variables